# Not able to access ajax post request parameters in struts2 controller class

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I am implementing simple login logic in my application. I have created a login.html and login.js files. In logins.js i am making a ajax post request and passing userId and password to struts controller class but both the values are null in my controller.

Below are my classes:

index.html

```xml
<form id="login-form" name="login-form" method="post" action="#">

   <table class="table_signin" >
  <!--email address table begins-->
  <tr>
 <th><label for="email" >Email Address</label></th>
 <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="input_width98 text"    style="text-transform: lowercase"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th><label for="password" >Password</label></th>
<td><input type="password" id="password" name="password"  class="input_width98 text" autocomplete="off"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

MyLogin.js is:

```
  $().ready(function() {
    $("#login").click(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
     if( email =='' || password =='')
      {
     $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]')
     $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]')
    alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
   }
  else{
  var userInfo= {"userEmail":email , "userPassword":password};

  alert("else part"+userInfo)
   var login = $.ajax({ 
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            url: "/nts-web/login/login.do", 
            data: userInfo,
            dataType: 'json',               
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,

            success: function (msg) {
            var res = msg;
            alert("res"+res);

          }     

        });
       }
    });
  });
```

Now my struts.xml contains below configuration:

```xml
  <package namespace="/login" name="login" extends="json-default">

    <action name="login" class="com.warnerbros.nts.controller.impl.AdminLoginControllerImpl" method="login">
    <interceptor-ref name="json" />
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

     <result type="json">
            <param name="root">result</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

And finally my LoginController is :

```
 public class AdminLoginControllerImpl extends AbstractControllerImpl implements AdminLoginController {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Autowired
 private LoginService loginService;

 private User userInfo;
 public String login() {
 System.out.println(userInfo.getUserEmailId());//Here it is throwing null pointer.
 String res= "";
 return res;
 }
}
```

and I have a pojo User.java like this:

```
 public class User {

private String userEmail;
private String userPassword;

public String getUserEmail() {
    return userEmail;
}
public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}
public String getUserPassword() {
    return userPassword;
}
public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
}
```

How to get the values useremail and password in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by sending the proper json object like

```
var obj = {"userInfo":{"userEmail":email , "userPassword":password}};
```

and in struts.xml below is the configuration.

```
<package namespace="/login" name="login" extends="json-default">

  <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="json">
                <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <action name="login"
        class="com.warnerbros.nts.controller.impl.AdminLoginControllerImpl"
        method="login">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <result type="json">
            <param name="root">result</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things mising.

1) If you need to send JSON to the Action, `you need the JSON Interceptor in your Interceptor Stack` to decode it correctly. You have only defined the JSON Interceptor, you've not applied it (along with the defaultStack) to the action; do it like follows:

```xml
<action name="login" class="foo.bar.AdminLoginControllerImpl" method="login">

    <interceptor-ref name="json"         />
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

    <result type="json">
        <param name="root">result</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

2) To work, the JSON Interceptor requires the `contentType` of the request to be `application/json`:

```
       ...
        dataType: 'json',               
     contentType: 'application/json',
       ...
```

3) The javascript code where you mount the data to send is wrong, the curl braces must not be escaped:

```js
// wrong
var userInfo = '{"userEmail":"'+email+'" , "password":"'+password+'}';
// right
var userInfo = {"userEmail":email , "password":password};
```

4) Your variables names don't match between the ones in the page and the one in the action. How do you expect `userEmail` to match `user.userEmailId` ? Or `password` to `user.userpassword` ?

Fix that and it should work.

Comment: what should be the name for interceptor-ref ? Can i give any name ?

Comment: O.o You can't give it any name. With `Interceptor-ref` you are `ref`erencing an `interceptor`, so you need to use the name of the interceptor you're referencing. You should usually use the defaultStack, that is a stack which internally has all the default interceptors. If you need to send json data from the JSP to the action, you need to use ALSO the json interceptor. Then you copy-paste what I've written, that is "use the json interceptor, and then use all the other default interceptors".

Comment: Also, since you are extending json-default, you've not even the need to *define* the interceptor in the <interceptors> tag

Comment: I've edited, I did not remember the contentType was needed to trigger it. Try like this